# Auto delete video after uploading on youtube

Tags: video, automation, youtube, upload

Is there any tools that will auto delete video from my hardrive after I uploaded it on youtube?

I uploading tens of videos regularly and it often hard to see what I can delete and what not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Move the files for a single batch into a separate folder and then delete the folder when the upload is done?